# Quais as diferenças entre as formas de injeção de dependências?

Tags: angularjs

Considerando a injeção de dependências no AngularJS, existem alguns modos de fazer. Os modos até onde eu sei são:

Forma 1:

```
angular
  .module('meuModulo', [])
  .controller('MeuController', function(dependencia)) {
    //...
  });
```

Forma 2:

```
angular
  .module('meuModulo', [])
  .controller('MeuController', ['dependencia', function(dependencia)) {
    //...
  }]);
```

Forma 3:

```
angular
  .module('meuModulo', [])
  .controller('MeuController', MeuController);

MeuController.$inject = ['dependencia'];

function MeuController(dependencia)) {
    //...
}
```

Eu usei como exemplo o `controller` mas dá pra utilizar para `factory`, `directive`, `filter`, etc.

Os meus questionamentos sobre isso são: Quais as reais diferenças entre as formas de injetar as dependências? Qual a indicação para cada caso? Tem outras formas de realizá-las?

Comment: Eu sempre uso a `forma 2` +1 pela pergunta ...

Comment: Sua 3ª opção parece mais adequada com os padrões de boas praticas. Recomendo dar uma lida no guia do John Papa, me ajudou bastante! https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md Espero ter ajudado. Abraço

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A forma 2 e 3 considera a posição do argumento, e não o nome.

Na minificação do Javascript, por exemplo, uma vez que os nomes das variáveis são alterados, poderia causar erros na sua aplicação em Angular.

O AngularJs lê o valor do parâmetro e injeta a dependência magicamente. Como a minificação faria `$scope` se transformar em `a`, poderia causar um erro dizendo que `a` não foi injectado.

Ou seja, o uso de `$inject` ou do `Array` com os nomes dos argumentos tem esse objetivo: Você está falando para o Angular injetar pela posição do parâmetro, e não pelo nome.

Assim, seria possível fazer algo como:

```
angular.module('app').controller(['$scope', '$http', (a, b) {
    console.log(a); // Retorna a instância de `$scope`
}]);
```

Comment: É verdade, inclusive no fórum do Angular recomenda não usar a forma 1. Se usar o ASP.Net e fizer o bundle dos arquivos Javascript, usando a primeira forma pode gerar erro de referência.

Answer (score 9):

Apenas uma resposta como alternativa, fornecendo um 4º método (que é o que eu uso), assim você tem mais alternativas.

A resposta do Wallace está perfeita, você deve ter em mente que se for executar minificação de código, é importante que você mantenha a ordem de injeção e dependências a mesma. Fazer isso manualmente pode ser trabalhoso e aumentar chances de erro.

É recomendado sempre utilizar a forma 2 ou 3. A diferença entre elas é apenas uma questão de preferência de código. Alguns preferem uma enquanto outros preferem a outra.

---

Se você usa `grunt`, pode usar [este plugin](https://github.com/mgol/grunt-ng-annotate) que vai facilitar muito a sua vida.

Este então seria o 4º método, pois você não precisa se preocupar em adicionar a injeção, ele faz isso automaticamente. Com base no seu exemplo, você poderia escrever seu código assim:

```
/* @ngInject */
.controller('MeuController', function(dependencia) {
    //...
});
```

E ele seria compilado para:

```
.controller('MeuController', function(dependencia) {
    //...
});
MeuController.$inject = ['dependencia'];
```

Deste modo você não se preocupa com a ordem delas. Se seu projeto tiver 10 injeções e você precisar remover uma que está ali no meio, não precisaria alterar manualmente a ordem.

Answer (score 5):

**Forma 1 (`Implicit Annotation`):**

É a maneira mais simples de lidar com as dependências e assume que as assinaturas dos parâmetros da função são nomes de dependências. No exemplo acima `dependencia` é um `service` que precisa ser injetado na função.
Uma das vantagens deste método é o de não haver um `array` de nomes para manter os parâmetros da função sincronizados. Você pode reorganizar as dependências livremente.
Entretando este método não irá funcionar com minificadores/ofuscados pelo fato dos parâmetros serem renomeados.
Por conta dessas ressalvas é recomendado evitar essa maneira.

**Forma 2 (`Inline Array Annotation`) :**

Este é o método recomentado de acordo com a [documentação do AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di). Assim passamos um array que consiste em uma lista de `strings` (os nomes das dependências) seguido pela função em si.
Quando utilizado esse tipo de anotação, é necessário ter cuidado para manter os parâmetros e a declaração da função sincronizados.

**Forma 3 (`$inject Property Annotation`):**

É o método indicado pelo [Angular Styleguide do John Papa](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection) (Um dos responsáveis pelo desenvolvimento do do AngularJS). Desta forma os minificadores ainda serão capazes de serem utilizados e injetar corretamente os services.
A função precisa ter a anotação da propriedade `$inject` que é um array dos nomes dos serviços injetados. Neste cenário a ordem dos valores injetados deve ser igual à ordem dos parâmetros na função.

---

**Referências:**

- [Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)
- [Manual Annotating for Dependency Injection](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection)