# Como minificar projeto em angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, minificação

Quando eu faço a minificação no angular tudo para de funcionar

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184816/inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-depend%C3%AAncia/184851#184851

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que o processo de minificação altera o nome dos parâmetros das funções. Não há problema algum nisso, contanto que o novo nome seja trocado em todos os lugares em que é usado, porém o sistema de injeção de dependências do Angular é baseado no nome dos parâmetros. A conclusão disso é que nada mais funcionará no Angular após a minificação, já que os parâmetros das funções serão trocados por outros nomes aleatórios e menores que não tem nada a ver.

Para solucionar este problema, o Angular possui o annotation system, um sistema de anotação que permite dizer o que deve ser injetado para cada parâmetro do controller, mesmo que seu nome seja trocado.

Exemplo:

```
angular.module('qualquer')
    .controller('QualquerController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
            // seu código 
    });
```

Vira:

```
angular.module('qualquer')
    .controller('QualquerController', [$scope, $routeParams] {
            //  seu código 
    });
```

Veja que o segundo parâmetro do controller é um array que recebe primeiro todos os artefatos que o controller do Angular receberá e por último a função que define o controller. O processo de minificação jamais tocará nos dados do array e o Angular segue a convenção que o primeiro parâmetro do array será injetado como primeiro parâmetro da função do controller. Se o nome do parâmetro da função do controller muda, tudo continuará funcionando.

Answer (score 5):

Como foi respondido antes, o processo de build renomeia as declarações de funções, mas preserva o array com o nome que deveria dar match na injeção de dependência.

Não sei ao certo como você está fazendo o processo de minificação, mas se estiver usando algum `task runner` como `Grunt`, `Gulp` ou `Webpack` o `ng-annotate` resolve a sua vida.

Ele preserva o nome das dependências importadas no processo de build.

Aqui tem a documentação: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate e aqui os tutoriais para usar com `task runners`: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate#tools-support

Comment: +1 pela menção ao `ng-annotate`. A pergunta é focada no processo de minificação, e não na alteração do conteúdo do projeto.